# Search Extensibility for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is search extensibility can be used for launching an application from a link?or this is only used for launching applications through bing search?

Answer (score 4):

Search extensibility is only for integration with the serch results displayed by Bing.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Silverlight SDK blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2011/12/20/updates-to-the-windows-phone-docs.aspx), search extensibility documentation just updated, so you can get information from primary source.